# Navigation Properties on Entity Framework not working with WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I'v make a EF Code-first model from a MariaDb Database over EF 6 with the MySql Connector, and also created a WCF Data Service to expose the entities to another apps.

Everything works fine, but navigation properties, are not working at all (Updates, modify, get, etc...)

I'm using Navigation Properties with the same EF Code-First Model on a Desktop Application and it's working properly, without problems.

I'v tried to disable Lazy Load and Proxy Creation, but the problem persists...

This is the code of my WCF Data Service...

```
public class WcfDataService1 : EntityFrameworkDataService<repartoEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

Navigation properties are not the problem since it works on Desktop, im using Entity Framework 6 with MySQL Connector on the latest version, .NET Framework 4.5.2...

Any help would be great!